# Automount USB disk (ntfs) and use files for libvirt/qemu/kvm?

Tags: virtualization, ntfs, kvm-virtualization, udisks

When I plugin my NTFS USB disk it gets auto-mounted. That's fine.
But when I want to use files for `libvirt/kvm/qemu` virtualizaztion they cannot be accessed. Sadly I cannot find the parameter or option to have `libvirt` and the `automount` working together.

Does anyone know the solution to my problem?

```
internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-system-x86_64: -drive 
file=/media/sascha/toshiba/ISO/otrs-3.3.9-appliance-1.0.9.iso,if=none,id=drive-
ide0-1-0,readonly=on,format=raw: could not open disk image /media/sascha/toshiba/ISO/otrs-
3.3.9-appliance-1.0.9.iso: Could not open '/media/sascha/toshiba/ISO/otrs-3.3.9-appliance-
1.0.9.iso': Permission denied
```